# Javascript - Age Verification

Tags: javascript, verification

Hey javascript masters,

Attempting to create an age verification page to a client's site. Code below is not functioning as it doesn't matter what year you select, it will still allow you to enter the site. Not sure what I should be looking at to correct.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function checkAge(f){
var dob=new Date();
var date=dob.getDate();
var month=dob.getMonth() + 1;
var year=dob.getFullYear();
var cmbmonth=parseInt(document.getElementById("cmbmonth").options[document.getElementById("cmbmonth").selectedIndex].value);
var cmbday=parseInt(document.getElementById("cmbday").options[document.getElementById("cmbday").selectedIndex].value);
var cmbyear=parseInt(document.getElementById("cmbyear").options[document.getElementById("cmbyear").selectedIndex].value);

age=year-cmbyear;

if(cmbmonth>month){age--;}
else{if(cmbmonth==month && cmbday>=date){age--;}}

if(cmbmonth==0){alert("You must enter the month you were born in.");return false;}
else if(cmbday==0){alert("You must enter the day you were born on.");return false;}
else if(cmbyear==2005){alert("You must enter the year you were born in.");return false;}
else if(age<13){alert("You are unable to view this site!");location.replace("http://www.dharmatalks.org");return false;}
else{return true;}

}

// --></script>
```

Comment: Note that `parseInt(document.getElementById("cmbmonth").options[document.getElementById("cmbmonth").selectedIndex].value);` can be `document.getElementById("cmbmonth").value;` and your keyboard won't wear out so fast. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Calculating age in years, months and days is a bit trickier than it should be due to the differences in month and year lengths. Here's a function that will return the difference between two dates in years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
function dateDifference(start, end) {

  // Copy date objects so don't modify originals
  var s = new Date(+start);
  var e = new Date(+end);
  var timeDiff, years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds;

  // Get estimate of year difference
  years = e.getFullYear() - s.getFullYear();

  // Add difference to start, if greater than end, remove one year
  // Note start from restored start date as adding and subtracting years
  // may not be symetric
  s.setFullYear(s.getFullYear() + years);
  if (s > e) {
    --years;
    s = new Date(+start);
    s.setFullYear(s.getFullYear() + years);
  }
  // Get estimate of months
  months = e.getMonth() - s.getMonth();
  months += months < 0? 12 : 0;

  // Add difference to start, adjust if greater
  s.setMonth(s.getMonth() + months);
  if (s > e) {
    --months;
    s = new Date(+start);
    s.setFullYear(s.getFullYear() + years);
    s.setMonth(s.getMonth() + months);
  }


  // Get remaining time difference, round to next full second
  timeDiff = (e - s + 999) / 1e3 | 0;
  days     =  timeDiff / 8.64e4 | 0;
  hours    = (timeDiff % 8.64e4) / 3.6e3 | 0;
  minutes  = (timeDiff % 3.6e3) / 6e1 | 0;
  seconds  =  timeDiff % 6e1;

  return [years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

You can abbreviate the above just after the year part and return just that if you want.

Note that in your code:

```
var cmbmonth=parseInt(document.getElementById("cmbmonth").options[document.getElementById("cmbmonth").selectedIndex].value);
```

can be:

```
var cmbmonth = document.getElementById("cmbmonth").value;
```

There is no need for *parseInt*, the Date constructor will happily work with string values. If you have used calendar month numbers for the values (i.e. Jan = 1) then subtract 1 before giving it to the Date constructor, but simpler to use javascript month indexes for the values (i.e. Jan = 0).

You can then do:

```
var diff = dateDifference(new Date(cmbyear, cmbmonth, cmbdate), new Date());
if (diff[0] < 18) {
  // sorry, under 18
}
```